# Not able to multimachine provision using vagrant with chef-solo

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, chef-solo

I am trying to do multi machine provision using vagrant with chef-solo . once I apply "vagrant up " command , my web recipe applyed to both vm1 and vm2 . similarly , others recipe get applyed to both VMs . But , I want only web recipe should be applied to VM1 and others recipe to VM2.  I am using chef-solo 12.3.0 .
my vagrant file is

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
   config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
   chef.cookbooks_path = "cookbooks"
   chef.add_recipe "pram::web"
   config.vm.define :vm1 do |server1|
   server1.vm.box = "ubuntu14"
   server1.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.102.101"
   end
   end
 config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
     chef.cookbooks_path = "cookbooks"
     chef.add_recipe "pram::others"
     config.vm.define :vm2 do |server2|
     server2.vm.box = "ubuntu14"
      server2.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.102.102"
          end
          end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , i got the solution of this problem . in 2nd line of code there should server1 instead of config. 
server1.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef| 
and this block of code should come under VM1 block . similarly , in 10th line it should be server2.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef| . 
otherwise given recipes will apply to all VMs that come under config block. 
correct solution is given below .

```
  Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
 config.vm.define :vm1 do |server1|
    server1.vm.box = "ubuntu14"
    server1.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.102.101"
    server1.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.cookbooks_path = "cookbooks"
    chef.add_recipe "pram::web"
    end
end
  config.vm.define :vm2 do |server2|
     server2.vm.box = "ubuntu14"
     server2.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.102.102"
     server2.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
     chef.cookbooks_path = "cookbooks"
     chef.add_recipe "pram::others"
     end
  end
```

end